# number of unique column value combinations with data.table

Tags: r, data.table

Let's say I have a data table like this:

```
smalldat <- data.table(group1 = rep(1:2, each = 3), 
                   group2 = rep(c('a','b'), times = 3,
                   value = 1:6)
```

That looks as follows:

```
group1    group2    value
1         a         1
1         b         2
1         a         3
2         b         4
2         a         5
2         b         6
```

I want to calculate the number of observed combinations of `group1` and `group2`.

The `dplyr` way would be (possibly not the most optimal):

```
nrow(smalldat %>% select(group1, group2) %>% distinct())
```

What would be the `data.table` way?

Comment: A differen dplyr approach would be `distinct(smalldat, group1, group2) %>% tally()` or for the sample data just `tally(distinct(smalldat))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `uniqueN` along with `.SD` and `.SDcols`:

```
smalldat[, uniqueN(.SD), .SDcols=group1:group2]
# [1] 4
```

---

Or even more efficient, as @DavidArenburg shows under comment:

```
uniqueN(smalldat, by=c("group1", "group2"))
# [1] 4
```

Comment: @DavidArenburg, forgot about `uniqueN`'s `by` arg. Nice! Please feel free to edit it in.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `unique` with the `by` option.

```
 nrow(unique(smalldat, by = c('group1', 'group2')))
```

Or

```
length(smalldat[,.GRP ,.(group1, group2)]$GRP)
```